# While-loop(if else statement)

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I want my program to input 9 numbers. If I input a number that is less than zero or greater than nine, it should loop back and will ask you again to input another number. The image attached is my program which has a problem.[image]

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int magic_square[][]=new int[3][3];
    int counter = 0;
    while(true){
      System.out.println("Enter the Magic Number: ");
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
          for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {
              System.out.println("Number "+(i+1)*(j+1));
              magic_square[i][j] = input.nextInt();
              if (magic_square[i][j] < 1 || magic_square[i][j] > 9)
                System.out.println("ERROR! Input range is invalid.");
              else
                counter++;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you define magic_square?

Comment: What do you need `counter` for? It's never used aside from incrementing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do away with the nested `for` loops and leverage the `counter` variable.

1. Simply use your `counter` variable: `counter/3` will point to the row and `counter%3` will point to the column.
2. `counter < 9` will help avoid the `while(true)` approach, which I don't personally recommend.

Also, your code is allowing invalid number into the array and proceeding to the next position, which is not the intended behaviour as per your post.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int magic_square[][]=new int[3][3];
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter the Magic Number: ");
    while(counter < 9){
      System.out.println("Number "+(counter+1));
      int input_num = input.nextInt();
      if (input_num < 1 || input_num > 9){
         System.out.println("ERROR! Input range is invalid.");
       } else {
          magic_square[counter/3][counter%3] = input_num;
          counter++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: It works but one more problem, it has an error. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at MP1.main(MP1.java:35)` It doesn't output the inputted numbers.

Comment: Oops. My bad. That's because I was incrementing the counter before setting it. I've corrected that and updated my answer